# How to get parent view to keep size while child re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of Views, with videos inside. Everytime the video loads, it takes a second, during which the container view has size 0. When the video loads, the view "pops" open, pushing everything in the list down and creating a kind of ugly, staggering effect. When I'm scrolling, I'm  unloading the videos that aren't visible anymore, but due to the "pop" effect, this causes the parent container views to go back to size 0, creating a reverse stagger effect.

It is possible for the container view to retain the height information even after the child video is unmounted?

Implementation details:
I'm using react-native-inview to figure out if the video is on the screen currently. If not, I replace it with an empty view component. This unmounts the video component on the next update.

```
<InView onChange={(isVisible) => {
                setIsInView(isVisible);
            }}>
    <MyVideo visible={isVisible} />
</InView>
```

MyVideo.js

```
import Video from 'react-native-video'
...
class Video extends React.Component {
    state = {
        vHeight: 0,
        vWeight: 0,
        maxWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        maxHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        muted: true,
        paused: false,
    };
render() { 
if (this.props.visible) {
return <Video
    muted={this.props.muted}
    paused={this.props.paused}
    repeat={true}
    source={{
        uri: this.props.data
            ? this.props.data.video
            : this.props.source.uri,
    }} // Can be a URL or a local file.
    ref={(ref) => {
        this.player = ref;
    }}
    // Rescale video on load
    style={{height: this.state.vHeight, width: this.state.vWidth}}
    onLoad={(response) => {
        this.setState({muted: true});
        const {height: vidHeight, width: vidWidth} = response.naturalSize;
        if (vidWidth > vidHeight || this.props.maxWidth) {
            const heightScaled =
                vidHeight *
                ((this.props.maxWidth || this.state.maxWidth) / vidWidth);
            this.setState({vHeight: heightScaled, vWidth: '100%'});
        } else {
            const widthScaled = vidWidth * (this.state.maxHeight / vidHeight);
            this.setState({
                vWidth: widthScaled,
                vHeight: this.state.maxHeight,
            });
        }
    }} />

} else {
            return (
                <View
                    style={{
                        height: this.state.vHeight,
                        width: this.state.vWidth,
                    }}
                />
            );
        }}
};
```

Comment: Can you show how you are unmounting videos, how you are mounting them, and what the config of the List component and Video components are? Also, do you have the video metadata available on the list elements? If so you can simply render some placeholder space for each element.

Comment: I'm using react-native-video and it doesn't have size metadata until the onLoad callback. So I don't know how big the placeholder space should be until the video is loaded. Is there still a way to implement placeholder space like that?

Comment: You can't render the proper height without knowing the proper height. I would recommend saving that metadata on the list elements or prefetching it from your object store. I can't help with the unmount stuff without seeing all the code, except to say that you probably don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "saving on the list elements"? As far as I know using state gets reset on every unmount

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of setting up FlatList for use with videos (taken from here https://medium.com/@jenshandersson/react-native-optimized-flatlist-of-videos-bb048cb696db)

```
//config for registering flatlist item viewability
viewabilityConfig = {
  waitForInteraction: false,
  minimumViewTime: 250,
  viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50
};

<FlatList
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  data={[{ url: "", meta: { height: 4, width: 3 } }]}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
  initialNumToRender={3}
  maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
  windowSize={5}
  getItemLayout={(_data, index) => ({
    length: cellHeight,
    offset: cellHeight * index,
    index,
  })}
  viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
  ListFooterComponent={
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.loadItems}>
      <Text style={{ padding: 30 }}>Load more</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
/>
```

They use `onViewableItemsChanged` to call `unload`, but they're using a different video implementation. For react-native-video, I would switch to the poster or a thumbnail image so that there's not too many paused videos in memory.